# Select specific fields from two inner joins

Tags: mysql

Given tables `Contracts`, `Contract_Plans` and `Contract_Plan_Tags`, can I select specific fields from all three within an inner join query?

Currently, I have

```
SELECT * FROM Contracts 
INNER JOIN Contract_Plans
ON Contracts.ContractNum = Contract_Plans.ContractNum
INNER JOIN Contract_Plan_Tags 
ON Contracts.ContractNum = Contract_Plan_Tags.ContractNum 
WHERE Contract_Plan_Tags.tag_id = 44 OR Contract_Plan_Tags.tag_id = 45
```

This query returns all the fields, but is there any way to select the specific fields from the join tables?

I know I can do

```
SELECT ContractNum, ContractName FROM Contracts
...
...
```

but that only selects fields from `Contracts`, not the other tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn about table aliases.  The best table aliases are short abbreviations of the tables.  You can then list the fields with the aliases:

```
SELECT c.ContractNum, c.ContractName, cpt.tag_id, . . .
FROM Contracts c
INNER JOIN Contract_Plans cp
ON c.ContractNum = cp.ContractNum
INNER JOIN Contract_Plan_Tags cpt
ON c.ContractNum = cpt.ContractNum 
WHERE cpt.tag_id in (44, 45)
```

I notice that you use table names in the `where` clause, so I hope I understand the question correctly.  You can use aliases (or table names) in the `select` and `where` (and `group by` and `having`) clauses.

Answer (score 2):

You must prefix the fields by their table name if order for MySQL to distinguish them:

```
SELECT Contracts.This, Contract_Plan_Tags.That, Contract_Plans.There FROM Contracts 
INNER JOIN Contract_Plans
ON Contracts.ContractNum = Contract_Plans.ContractNum
INNER JOIN Contract_Plan_Tags 
ON Contracts.ContractNum = Contract_Plan_Tags.ContractNum 
WHERE Contract_Plan_Tags.tag_id = 44 OR Contract_Plan_Tags.tag_id = 45
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can select any field from any table from the `FROM` clause. If two fields of two tables have the same name, then you **must** prefix the field with the name of the table (or else you get an error from the parser: "field name is ambiguous").

You **may** prefix the unambiguous field names too if you find it more readable.

In fact it works exactly the same way as in the `WHERE` clause.

Incidentally, the same requirement exists if you join tables from several databases. If two tables have the same name, you must prefix their name with the database name, but do not need to if the name is unambiguous.

Oh and you can also do this: `SELECT table1.*, table2.some_field, table3.* FROM...`